# use nested functions in matlab M-file

Tags: matlab

i have question,about which i am  too much interested,suppose that i have two M-file in matlab,  in  the first one i have described  following function for calculating peaks and  peaks indeces

```
function [peaks,peak_indices] = find_peaks(row_vector)
    A = [0 row_vector 0];
    j = 1;
    for i=1:length(A)-2
        temp=A(i:i+2);
        if(max(temp)==temp(2))
            peaks(j) = row_vector(i);
            peak_indices(j) = i;
            j = j+1;
        end
    end
end
```

and   in second M-file i have  code for  describing  sinusoidal   model for given data  sample

```
function [ x ]=generate(N,m,A3)

f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))';
wn = rand(length(t),1).*2 - 1;
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;

end
```

my question is how  to combine it together?one solution would be  just create  two M-file into folder,then  call function  from one M-file  and made operation on given vector and get result,and then  call second function from another  M file  on given result and finally get  what we  want,but i  would like to build it in one big M-file,in c++,in java,we can create classes,but i am not sure if we can do same in matlab too,please help me to clarify  everything and  use  find_peaks  function into  generate function

**UPDATED:**
ok now  i would like to show  simple change what i have made in my code

```
function [ x ] = generate(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = rand(length(t),1).*2 - 1;
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
end
```

i used  findpeaks  built-in function in matlab,but i am getting following error

```
generate(1000,50,50)
Undefined function 'generate' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

also i am interested what would be effective sampling rate to avoid  alliasing?

Comment: If you aim to write object-oriented codes within MATLAB (as in java and c++), you can easily achieve that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this, within a single **MATLAB** script

```
function test()
clc, clear all, close all
x = generate(1000,50,50);
[p,i] = find_peaks(x)
end

function x = generate(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = rand(length(t),1).*2 - 1;
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
end

function [peaks,peak_indices] = find_peaks(row_vector)
    A = [0;row_vector;0];
    j = 1;
    for i=1:length(A)-2
        temp=A(i:i+2);
        if(max(temp)==temp(2))
            peaks(j) = row_vector(i);
            peak_indices(j) = i;
            j = j+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: but when i run test,it shows only  some values not,indexes for exmaple

Comment: I edited the answer. btw I would suggest to work around your peak function, you could avoid for loops.

Comment: use function  findpeaks from matlab?how can i use it?

Comment: @fpe It should be noted that the term "script" in MATLAB regards an m-file that cannot accept input and doesn't produce output values, and as such does not contain the `function` keyword. On the other hand, what you implemented is a _function_ `test` that also contains local functions `generate` and `find_peaks`.

Comment: @EitanT: you're right, sometimes I over-use the term **script**. Btw, I guess that the OP is asking for something similar to what I did, didn't he?

Comment: ok i will delete my question and  open new one,it is possible?

Comment: because i   have changed  my code and  how can i show it?ok i will try to update

Comment: i have eddited,please  see it

Answer (score 4):

You can simply put both in one file. The file must have the same name as the first function therein, and you will not be able to access subsequently defined functions from outside that file. See the MATLAB documentation on functions http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/function.html (particularly the examples section).

Also note that MATLAB has a built-in function findpeaks().

(By the way, you're still sampling at too low a frequency and will most certainly get aliasing - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions )

Edit: As you requested it, here is some more information on the sampling theorem. A good and simple introduction to these basics is http://www.dspguide.com/ch3/2.htm and for further reading you should search for the Shannon/Nyquist sampling theorem.

Comment: so what would be relevant  sampling  rate?

Comment: also error is this  Undefined function 'generate' for input arguments of type 'double'.